# SQL multiple SETs in one UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a SQL field like so:

```
FIELD_A  
  cat     
  dog 
  bird
  mole
  dog
```

I want to `UPDATE`

- all *dog* to *pug*
- all *bird* to *owl*
- all *cat* to *angora*.

Apparently, the SQL `UPDATE`statement only allows one `SET` condition at a time.

How can I write a query to accomplish the above operation all at once?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
UPDATE AnonymousTable
   SET Field_A = (CASE Field_A
                  WHEN 'dog'  THEN 'pug'
                  WHEN 'bird' THEN 'owl'
                  WHEN 'cat'  THEN 'angora'
                  ELSE Field_A END)
 WHERE Field_A IN ('dog', 'bird', 'cat');
```

With the WHERE clause, the ELSE clause in the CASE expression is optional or redundant - but including the ELSE gives you reliability.  One of the more serious mistakes is not to cover that 'none of the above' alternative and find that everything that wasn't mentioned is set to NULL.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `WHERE Field_A IN ('dog', 'bird', 'cat');` ?  Why include the `WHERE`?

Comment: @Steve: there is no compulsion to include the WHERE clause if you include the ELSE clause in the CASE expression.  However, if you have 30 million rows in your table, and only 1 million of those rows contain 'dog', 'cat' or 'bird' in Field_A, then the UPDATE with WHERE updates 1 million rows instead of 30 million rows, which radically reduces the workload on your machine.  OTOH, if you have 5 rows in the table, it doesn't matter in the slightest.

Comment: Clear as a bell, which is to say, quite clear.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

with CASE clause you can accomplish this. here an example

http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Select-Query/UseCASEintheUPDATEstatement.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table_a
   SET field_a =
          DECODE (field_a,  'dog', 'pug',  'bird', 'owl',  'cat', 'angora')
 WHERE field_a IN ('dog', 'bird', 'cat');
```

Comment: With the WHERE clause, omitting a final 'default' column is safe.  You could add `, field_a` after `'angora'` and be safe even if the WHERE clause was omitted.